# Re-sizing a JInternalFrame kept inside a parent JFrame and this Parent JFrame is registered with ComponentMover API

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am pretty bad with english so please forgive me for grammatical mistakes. I am new in java swings, my intent is to create many jinternalframes dynamically and each jintenalframe is to be movable i.e. free to drag and be kept anywhere, which i have achieved through component mover class. Now the problem which i am facing is that i am unable to resize these internalframes. whenever i am resizing these jinternalFrames they are getting back to same size. 
I have even registered with resizing event with component listener below code depicts that:

```
this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce)
    {
      setDinamicSize(ce)
    }
}); 

private void setDinamicSize(ComponentEvent ce)
{
    JInternalFrame tempFrame = (JInternalFrame)ce.getSource();
    tempFrame.setSize(new Dimension(tempFrame.getAlignmentX(),tempFrame.getAlignmenty()));
}
```

please help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use `JDesktopPane`?  If created properly, the `JInternalFrame` should moveable and resizable without any additional code...

Comment: actually internal frames are to be kept inside a frame. since each jinternalframe represents a game room

Comment: But what are you adding the `JInternalFrame`s to?  They're suppose to be used with a `JDesktopPane`...

Comment: All of them? To a single `JFrame`?  Or each one to it's own `JFrame`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer all of them to a single parent jframe

Comment: Right, so add a `JDesktopPane` to you `JFrame` and then add your `JInternalFrame`s to the `JDesktopPane` like they're suppose to be, as demonstrated in [How to use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)...problem solved

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok i'll try and let you know . Thanks a lot mate for giving your precious time.

Comment: Always happy to reduce the workload of others ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer nopes still i'm unable to resize. I think their could be some conflict at mouse's listener so may i post ComponentMover class. Its actually lil'bit lengthy so i can mail too.

Comment: Try not using your `ComponentMover` class, just the `JDesktopPane` and `JInteralFrame`...

Answer (score 5):

`JDesktopPane` is a container for `JInternalFrame`s which takes care of things like positioning and (if you've constructed the internal frames correctly) resizing...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestDesktopPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDesktopPane();
    }

    public TestDesktopPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane();
                JInternalFrame inFrame = new JInternalFrame("No Hands", true, true, true, true);
                inFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
                inFrame.setVisible(true);
                pane.add(inFrame);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Check out [How to use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more details

Comment: (claps hands in delight)  Now make it go clockwise!

Comment: @MadProgrammer hats off to you :) :)